# Join tables based on 30 second time difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase, dateadd

I had a table of buy/sell transactions that I separated to have one table of only buy transactions and one table of only sell transactions. I want to rejoin these two tables and match the buy with a sell where the product is the same, and the execution time between the buy and sell are between 10 and 30 seconds of each other.

I have tried to left join the two tables and use DATEADD for the time increments, but I am returned an error message.

Ideally I would like the new table to include all the columns from the buy table and sell table, but the columns I need for the match are product and execution_time from both.

Error message I get:- `"invalid data type comparison in predicate"`

```
ON b.product = a.product AND b.execution_time >= DATEADD(second, 30, a.execution_time)
```

The 30 second portion is more important than 10 seconds right now, it can be 0-30.

Comment: which one mysql or sql server? tag correctly?

Comment: What was the error message and what was the query you tried?

Comment: add your tried query also?

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Did you mean to ask a question? That error message "`invalid data type comparison in predicate`", I don't think that's from MySQL; I've never gotten that before (and I've generated a whole boatload of errors over the years); I don't see that error message in the MySQL Reference manual. And `DATEADD()` is not a native MySQL function. MySQL has similarly named `DATE_ADD()` and a `ADDDATE()` functions...

Comment: My apologies, it's actually in sybase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Sybase Datediff](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/Datediff.htm) to get desired result

**MYSQL:-**

```
SELECT B.* 
from tblBuy B INNER JOIN tblSell S
ON B.product = S.product
Where  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(B.execution_time ,S.execution_time )) BETWEEN 10 AND 30;
```

**SYBASE:-**

```
SELECT B.* 
from tblBuy B INNER JOIN tblSell S
ON B.product = S.product
Where  DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.execution_time, S.execution_time) BETWEEN 10 AND 30;
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but it was my mistake. I'm using sql in sybase, not mysql. Unfortunately, time_to_sec doesn't work for me.

Comment: @nciaf:- previously you tag your question with MYSQL tag, now you changed that

Comment: I did, as I said it was a mistake on my part. Trying to help a friend with a large data set, I haven't spent much time working with sql or mysql.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for the response. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @nciaf:- not a problem...cheermate